# Retrieving data from multiple text files in java

Tags: java, arrays, io, inputstream

I'm trying to retrieve data from multiple text files(say songs) and record them into an array. The problem is, all array values have the LAST FILE's values. Here's a part of code

```
  public static Song[] retrieve(String path, String type, String g, int no)

       {
        Song[] song;
        song = new Song[no];

        Scanner s;
        String lrc = "";

        for(int i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(path+"\\"+type+"\\"+g+"\\"+(i+1)+".txt"));

                song[i].artist = s.nextLine();
                song[i].title = s.nextLine();
                song[i].genre = "ARB";
                while(s.hasNext())
                    lrc = lrc + " " + s.next();
                song[i].lyrics = lrc.split(" ");
                lrc = "";
                s.close();
                /*System.out.println(song[i].artist);
                System.out.println(song[i].title);
                System.out.println(song[i].genre);
                for(int j = 0; j < song[i].lyrics.length; j++)
                    System.out.print(song[i].lyrics[j]+" ");
                System.out.println("")*/

            } catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }
        }

        return song;
    }
```

Comment: Here you are taking inputs from single file only, so you will get it from single file only.

Comment: Please post the lines where you call this function as well

Comment: Does it print the information correctly in the for loop by using the println statements that u have commented out?

Comment: Song[] song;
        //song = new Song[20];
        
        song = retrieve("D:\\workspace\\464\\src\\pkg464\\Songs","Train","ARB",20);

Comment: yes it correctly outputs the last file's data in every array point

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included all of your method's code.  The code you have posted would throw a NullPointerException, because `new Song[no]` creats a new array whose values are all null.  The first time `song[i].artist = …` is encountered, song[i] would be null and the exception would be thrown.

My guess is that your actual code (which we can't see) is calling `new Song()` only once, and then is doing something like this:

```
Song newSong = new Song();
for (int z = 0; z < no; z++) {
    song[z] = newSong;
}
```

That causes all elements of the array to point to the *same* instance.  It doesn't create 20 Song objects, it just creates 20 references to one Song.  So your loop is accessing the right array element, but each time, that array element is pointing to the same Song object.

The correct thing to do is to put this line *inside* your loop:

```
song[i] = new Song();
```